# SQLite3: dynamic between query

Tags: sqlite, reverse, between

I have this sqlite3 table (simplified):

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| ROUTE  | WPNumber |  WPID |
+--------+----------+-------+
|  A123  |    1     | WP001 |
|  A123  |    2     | WP002 |
|  A123  |    3     | WP003 |
|  [...] |   [...]  | [...] |
|  A123  |    20    | WP020 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

Lets say I want to travel this route in the reverse direction (020 to 001).

How do I get all the WPID's in between? I know it is possible to build a query using BETWEEN and DESC, but then I'd have to build two seperate queries and have Python check when to use which query. Is it possible to have sqlite3 do the work, independent of the direction (reverse or not).

Comment: How should the query know which direction to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the sorting order by reversing the number used in the `ORDER BY` clause.
Set the parameter `?` to either `1` or `-1`:

```sql
SELECT WPID
FROM ThisTable
WHERE ROUTE = 'A123'
ORDER BY WPNumber * ?
```

If you would just use a similar query with `DESC`, the database would have a better opportunity to optimize the sorting with an index.